# FFmpeg - Writing a script to define fontcolor of each word in a text file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a text file with a lot of word separated by newline character like this

```
apple
banana
strawberry
```

And I have a list of colors I want those word to appear in

```
0xFF0000
0xFFFF33
0xFF0045
```

Also I'm using command like this

`x=:'lte(t,10.99)*0+between(t,11,42.99)*10+between(t,43,643.99)*20+gte(t,644)*30':y='lte(t,10.99)*0+between(t,11,42.99)*10+between(t,43,643.99)*20+gte(t,644)*30'`

to move those words around.

Is it possible to somehow script ffmpeg to color those words and also move them all in one command?

Comment: Use ASS or SRT subtitles instead, or separate drawtext instances per line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! `SAA,ASS` looks really promising.

Comment: Download Aegisub for making subtitles. It's easy to use and if you run into problems, 
there are plenty of help videos on YouTube.  http://www.aegisub.org/